# How to create a real time location sharing android app

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, android-gps

I want to create an app where people can see where they and their friends are
Eg: - imagine 2 people are using the app they should be able to see each other's location in real time and they should be able to navigate to each other 
Can someone help me get the resources for creating such an app

Answer (score 17):

Building real-time location sharing app requires two major things:

- Google Fused Location API (On Device Side)
- A two-way communication channel between device and server.

Using above those in parallel to generate location data and send it to the server needs to be a fine balance between accuracy and battery drain.

You can use the [HyperTrack](https://www.hypertrack.com/) SDK to build real-time location sharing feature in few steps.

**Step 1**

Follow [setup](https://docs.hypertrack.com/sdks/android/setup.html) guide to integrate HyperTrack SDK

**Step 2**

Use SDK [method](https://docs.hypertrack.com/sdks/android/actions.html#step-2-assigning-actions-to-a-user) `HyperTrack.createAndAssignAction` using `lookupID` and `expectedPlace` to generate location sharing tracking URL to share with your friend.

Using tracking URL your friends can track you.

**Step 3**

On the other end you can fetch tracking detail from tracking URL to create another action to share your friend location using the same `lookupID` and `expectedPlace` and to fetch the `lookupID` and `expectedPlace`, call SDK [method](https://docs.hypertrack.com/sdks/android/reference/action.html#get-actions-for-lookup-id) `HyperTrack.getActionsForLookupId` and repeat Step 2.

**Step 4**

Now to see the updated location in google map layout on your phone, you can integrate [Live Tracking View](https://docs.hypertrack.com/usecases/livetracking/android/installing.html) provided by SDK. After integration happens, call `HyperTrack.trackActionByLookupId` [method](https://docs.hypertrack.com/usecases/livetracking/android/installing.html) using the same lookupID to see the real-time updating location of your friends.

You can also refer to the implementation of live location sharing feature [here](https://www.hypertrack.com/tutorials/live-location-sharing-android-messaging-app) and we have open-sourced our live location sharing app https://github.com/hypertrack/hypertrack-live-android .

Feel free to ask anything.

[image]

Disclaimer: I was an engineer of HyperTrack.

We have worked hard to make the SDK battery efficient and accurate without compromising on realtime-ness of the locations data. In case of issue, we provide any kind of [technical support](http://slack.hypertrack.com/) required during and after integration.

Comment: This question is off-topic but great answer, If it’s not flagged as spam because of the disclaimer.

Comment: Hi Aman, It's a nice API but paid, I think it should be free for some users. I want to know about the web part that how we can check the live location of the user.

Answer (score 9):

Get location of user and  send it to Firebase. All users, subscribed to changes of that field in Firebase will be notified at the time of update or as soon as they get Internet connection.

Comment: How it will be possible in the background? Can we send data to the firebase database in the background?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop this type of application then need to understand all of following point:

**Location API** 
- You need to understand about location api which will provide you live location data using combination of cell tower data or Wifi Signal and GPS, Fusion Location api is the good one as per my understanding, another also available,

**API for Live live update** 
 - You need to configure API or mechanism which update live location on your server or friend.
As per my concern if you use socket for that is good other wise also you can firebase as the best one,

**List of application which like this** 
- Life360, GeoZill, e.t.c,

Comment: thanks, Let me know socket means which need to use Node.js or Java to updating the live location to server database continuously.